# Rails 4 using www prefix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a domain with ssl running rails app. Currently on production I already enabled `config.force_ssl = true`, the ssl works perfectly. Now the issues is, if I typed `example.com` it redirect to `https://example.com` but I need it to redirect back to `https://www.example.com`.

My rails app running on AWS. Thanks!!

Comment: You will have to modify your DNS settings for that.